# Distinct value for multiple values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to find distinct value based on 3 columns. Here the Query which I am trying

```
select * from messages where (message_from=4 or message_to=4) group by message_from,message_to,bidpost_id
ORDER BY `messages`.`message_id` ASC
```

which gives me following output:
[image]

but I don't want message id 5 because it has already comes before as message_from and message_to is already comes in message_id = 4

I want distinct value on base of bidpost_id, message_from and message_to

Note: message_from and message_to pair must be unique

My desirable output is:
[image]

Comment: Would you want `message_id` `6`? It has a `message_from` and `message_to` of `4 | 3` which is already in `message_id` `2`. Same questino about `9` and `14`. If not why is `5` special?

Comment: No i want message_id 6, because bidpost_id for message_id 6 and 2 is different

Comment: for message_id 4 and 5 bidpost_id is same for value pair (4,1)

Comment: Awesome. That would have been my guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a `join` or `exists`.  For example:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where not exists (select 1
                  from messages m2
                  where m2.bidpost_id = m.bidpost_id and
                        m2.message_from in (m.message_to, m.message_from) and
                        m2.message_to in (m.message_to, m.message_from) and
                        m2.message_id < m.message_id
                 );
```

This returns the first message (based on `message_id`) for those three columns.

Another method that doesn't use explicit join is:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.message_id in (select min(m.message_id)
                       from messages m
                       group by bidpost_id,
                                least(message_from, message_to),
                                greatest(message_from, message_to)
                      );
```

Performance might not be as good for this, even with the recommended index on `messages(bidpost_id, message_from, message_to, message_id)`.

Comment: I want to get all records for message_from or message_to for id 4 only, your suggestion still giving me message_id 4 and 5

Answer (score 0):

I done with this solution:

```
select message_id, value1, value2, bidpost_id from (select message_id, `bidpost_id`, 
least(`message_from`, `message_to`) as value1
, greatest(`message_from`, `message_to`) as value2
from `messages` group by value1, value2, bidpost_id order by message_id) as t where value1= 4 or value2 =4
```

Thanks to Gordon Linoff, I took some code from your answer from another post